# How to sort columns in a dataframe such that the values in the first row are from largest to smallest?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following dataframe:

|  | Audi | Hyundai | Kia | Mercedes | Tesla | VW | Volvo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 0.25 | nan | nan | 0.5 | nan | nan | 0.25 |
| 2020 | nan | 0.125 | nan | 0.375 | 0.125 | 0.125 | 0.25 |
| 2021 | nan | nan | 0.25 | 0.5 | nan | 0.25 | nan |

I want to rearrange the columns such the the first row is sorted from largest to smallest. So the order of the columns should be Mercedes, Audi/Volvo, the rest.

I tried `df.sort_values()` so many times, but I always get errors. The most common error is about the usage of by.

Comment: can you provide text as input, not an image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reorder the columns based on the sorted order of the first row:

```
out = df[df.iloc[0].sort_values(ascending=False).index]
print(out)

# Output
      Mercedes  Audi  Volvo  Hyundai   Kia  Tesla     VW
2019     0.500  0.25   0.25      NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
2020     0.375   NaN   0.25    0.125   NaN  0.125  0.125
2021     0.500   NaN    NaN      NaN  0.25    NaN  0.250
```

Comment: I love you :). There goes my entire day trying to make sort_values() work :(

Comment: alternative `df.iloc[:, np.argsort(df.iloc[0].mul(-1).tolist())]`